# How to add tabs in the title bar with Pyside?

Tags: python, qt, tabs, pyside, titlebar

In Windows, Firefox and Chrome put some of their UI in the title bar. I know the [secret](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5558118/1931274) to how they do this.
I want to do the same, with PySide, (without re-implementing all of the window features) but how can this be done in Python?

PS: Google got me to a [thread](https://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/3331), closed in favour of a dead one.

Comment: It can be done for QWidgets using native winapi code. However it's not that simple in pyside, where you cannot just run C++ code in a native event handler. Maybe you will need to write a native extension of some sort.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pyqt tabs like in Google Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630851/pyqt-tabs-like-in-google-chrome)

Comment: @Trilarion Well, point 2 is what I wish to avoid.. I edited OP to include that.